# git merge images with conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge

I am working on a branch and I want to merge another branch to mine. And I want to make sure I take all the changes from that branch to mine because that branch has all the front-end changes and none of the files of backend has been touch. So by doing the merge I should be able to keep my change and bring in all the change from the incoming branch. But the problem is incoming branch has deleted the some of the images or rename the image files etc. Due to this I have conflicts. What is the best way to resolve this?

I was thinking to checkout my current branch to different place delete all the image files and check in do a pull and then do the merge but I feel like there is a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to address these conflicts a file at a time. Are any of the renamed or missing files for the "back end" or is it all front end changes? If the donor branch has changes you don't need then you need to not accept those changes, or rather enforce that your changes are what to keep.

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that all of the files that you own are in the state that you want them in in your branch regardless of what happened in the other branch and vice versa, then you can simply get all the files from you branch with

```
git checkout --theirs -- .
git checkout --ours -- paths/to/frontend
git add -A
git commit
```

`--theirs` and `--ours` refers to the each branch's state before the merge occurred.